# miss some characters when do AES 256 decryption in objc

Tags: python, objective-c, aes, ios6

The code of encrypt method in python (2.6):

```
key += PADDING * (32 - len(key))
pad_it = lambda s: s+(16 - len(s)%16)*PADDING
crypt = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, 'J2-+sfd%932mIt:{')
data = crypt.encrypt(pad_it(data))
```

The code of decrypt method in objc (iOS6):

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted );
```

I encrypt a plist file with the python, and then decrypt it with objc,
but when debug in objc (iOS6), the decrypted data missed some characters at the end of file's content.

Did anybody also meet this issue, and can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: is there any `'\0'` in the file?

Answer (score 1):

kCCOptionPKCS7Padding isn't set properly, therefore iOS6 is dropping the last 16-byte block.
The iOS5, when the padding was not set properly, it would treat it as not specified.

Comment: perhaps you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596280/cccrypt-difference-between-ios5-and-ios6 ?